# What is this set $\mathbb{R}$ mod $2\pi$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

What does it mean for S = $\mathbb{R}$ mod $2\pi$? Can someone please explain as this notation is new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that $x\equiv y$ if and only if $x=y+2k\pi$ for some integer $k.$ It is the same when you watch your clock. Then hour $13$ is equal to hour $1$ just because you understand hours mod $12.$ That is $13-1=12.$

The model for your $\mathbb{R}\: \mathrm{mod}\: 2\pi$ is a circumference of radius $1.$ There you can identify $1$ with $1+2\pi,$ $1-2\pi,$ etc.

Comment: But what is this set? Does $S  = \mathbb{R}$ mod $2\pi$ mean $S = \{y | x = y + 2k\pi, for x \in \mathbb{R}, k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

Comment: As I have said you can identify this set with a circumference of radius $1.$ As @Prospect says in his/her answer this set is obtained as the set of equivalence classes of an equivalence relation. In his/her answer he/she gives explicitly the equivalence relation. I think that the clock is a good model.

Answer (score 3):

First, define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\mathbf{R}$ via $x \sim y$ if there exists an integer $k$, such that $x - y = 2\pi k$. Verify that this is indeed an equivalence relation. Representatives of its equivalence classes are then elements of $\mathbf{R} \mod{2 \pi}$.

Notice that this is analogous to defining modulo integers.

Comment: What is the common between equivalence relation and this modulo operation. I have not encountered this before is this number theory?

Comment: Same thing, except $x,y \in \mathbf{Z}$ and $2\pi$ would be replaced by an integer.

Answer (score 1):

$\Bbb{R}\mod M$ means real numbers ($\Bbb{R}$) such that $0\leq x < M$.  So for example $\Bbb{R}\mod  2\pi$ means all real numbers in the half-open interval $[0,2\pi)$, an interval often used when talking about angles or the modulus of a complex number.

Although in set theory that is the end of the story, usually when such a set is *used*, we are going to also have rules of arithmetic modulo $2\pi$, that is, for example, $3 \cdot \frac{4\pi}{5} = \frac{2\pi}{5}$.

Comment: so $x \in \mathbb{R}$ mod $M$ is $x \in [0, M)$. This is simpler to understand...